# calling column name from array oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

my table looks like:

```
Name Salary Salary_1 Salary_2

AAA       100          70          80

BBB       120         100         110

CCC       20           25          30
```

This what I want to do is to save sum for each salaries (so for salary, salary_1 and salary_2). I've created the pl/sql block:

```
    declare
type col is table of varchar2(8);
type suma is table of number;
v_col col:=col('SALARY','SALARY_1','SALARY_2');
v_suma suma:=suma();

begin
 for i in 1..3 loop
   v_col.extend();
   v_suma.extend();
select sum(v_col(i)) 
into  v_suma(i) from employees;
dbms_output.put_line('value : ' ||v_suma(i));
end loop;

end;
```

In dbms_output I get:

```
value : 
value : 
value :
```

I think that I cannot call column names like that from the varray. Am I correct?
Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Many thanks for your help

Kamil

Comment: Your code gives ORA-01722: invalid number. Are you sure you posted the right code?

Comment: You've got it. You can't dynamically add a column name into a SQL statement... directly. You can, however, dynamically build a SQL statement as a string, then execute the string using [execute immediate](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01115) You might also consider changing your schema to having a single `salary` field and a new field for `salary_type` with either value `1` or `2`. then you can tackle this with native sql.

Comment: thanks guys for your comments

Answer (score 0):

You are right; you cannot sum the columns the way you are trying it. `sum(v_col(i))` simply multiplies the content of `v_col(i)` (which is null) with the number of records in the table.

However, you don't need a loop to get the three sums:

```
declare
  type suma is table of number;
  v_suma suma := suma();
begin
  v_suma.extend(3);

  select sum(salary), sum(salary_1), sum(salary_2)
  into v_suma(1), v_suma(2), v_suma(3)
  from employees;

  for i in 1 .. 3 loop
    dbms_output.put_line('value : ' || v_suma(i));
  end loop;
end;
```